# Automatically update attribute of Ruby object via REST URL with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

What's the best way in Ruby/Rails to use URL parameters to automatically set an attribute once clicked. Like a REST call. For example:

Class: Person
Attribute: age

Link example: 
http://1.2.3.4:3000/persons/2345/edit?age=21

Once the link is clicked, I would want the code to be executed, leading an success/error page.

Is there a recommended gem? I would prefer not to use a gem if this is simple, especially if I can do this simply in routes or the controller.

So far, in routes I'm trying:

```
get 'person/:id/update/:age', to: 'persons#update'
```

In controller:

```
def update
    respond_to do |format| 
      @person  = Person.find(params[:id])
      if @person.update(person_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @person }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

but I get an error saying:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: person
```

Comment: You REALLY shouldn't be doing any updates via GET requests. Not only is that not RESTful, but that's very insecure. Also, can you include more of the stack trace and the controller code (e.g. where you define `person_params`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this in routes.rb :

```
#routes.rb
resources :persons
```

and this in edit.html.erb :

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :age , value:21 %>
  <%= f.submit 'set 21 years old' %>
<% end %>
```

The url of the request will be 'person/:id', and {age:21} will be encoded in the POST HTTP request.